# How to rewrite a folder path

Tags: magento-1.9, url, url-rewrite, admin-panel, .htaccess

I need to create a redirect that will redirect from https://www.example.com/es to https://www.example.com/mx for all pages on my site. How would I go about that. Can I do that in Magento admin section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to handle this would be to use htaccess redirect.

Magento admin does have a simple redirect admin under

Catalog > URL Redirects